# get error while importing my sql database

Tags: mysql, joomla

https://ufile.io/4d2ce

This is the link of my db I am getting while importing this database kindly help me I want to import in mysql using wamp server but not able to import it.

Comment: https://s3.postimg.org/waegi775v/error.png

Comment: this is the screen shot of error I get

Answer (score 0):

Seems you miss the `COMMENT` value for `parent_id`.

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
 `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'PK',
 `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'YOUR_COMMENT_HERE'
);
```

[EDITED] Next time you should write the query and the error in your question instead of attach an image to make us easier help you.

Good luck